# Change default status to on-hold when creating an order manually in Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

I have two questions. When I add an manual order in WooCommerce, the default status is `Pending`. How can i get this default status on `on-hold`?

Is it possible to hide the `Pending` status completely in WooCommerce? I don't want to use this status because I only get orders with an invoice at an later moment.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read the docs on [Managing Orders with WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-orders/). `Pending` is typically assigned when an order goes all the way to checkout but does not complete the order (like for a failed transaction). It sounds like `Pending` is what you should be using and not `on-hold` for those invoiced orders.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible using the custom code below, that will remove "pending status" option and **enabling "on-hold" status** option only when adding a new order manually in backend:

```
add_action('in_admin_footer', 'hide_default_order_status');
function hide_default_order_status () {
    global $pagenow;

    if( $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order' && $pagenow == 'post-new.php'){
        ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(document).ready( function($){
                $('select#order_status option[value="wc-pending"]').remove();
                $('select#order_status').val('wc-on-hold');
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Hi! This wordt great, but te new default status is now 'processing'. How can we make the default status 'on-hold'?